# How Accss JsonData from given image

Tags: ios, json, iphone, swift, swift3

array product model[detail models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du1QY.png)

My code:

```
productDetailsNameLabel.text = products[indexPath.section].arr_details?[indexPath.item].productname
```

Getting error message:

> Type Arr_Details has no subscripts member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arr_details not have any subscript members so you cannot access it. Please refer following example:

```
class Abc: NSObject {
   var arr: [Xyz] = []
   override init() {
       for i in 1...5 {
           arr.append(Xyz(number: i))
       }
   }
}

class Xyz: NSObject {
    var number: Int
    init(number: Int) {
        self.number = number
    }
}
// Use of this class
var arrAbc: [Abc] = []
for _ in 0...5 {
    arrAbc.append(Abc())
}
yourLabel.text = "\(arrAbc[0].arr[0].number)"
```

Comment: productDetailsNameLabel.text = products[indexPath.section].arr_details?[indexPath.item].productname   it create model of products and arr_details .  how assign value to label after json called, i have 5 item array in product class.so please help me.  if you want whole json data. i will share....

Comment: products itself array of product and the arr_details is array defined in Product model and productname should be member of Class of arr_details array.

Comment: Already define.. how assign details data to label. i m trying this self.productDetailsNameLabel.text = self.details[indexPath.item].product_name but not working . error show array index of bound, please fix the issue

Comment: You are accessing the array out of bounds so this issue occurs, Please check your collectionview items and elements of array you are using  to fill the collectionview.

Comment: refer two image i have added. what is problem on my question. please help me

Answer (score 0):

arr_details doesn't have a subscript so that it doesn't return a value. 
In order to use the subscript, you have to implement it on the arr_detail type.

Comment: please explain with Example!!